# Linear algebra question on row operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices with the same row reduced form then there is a sequence of row operations which takes $A$ to $B$.

I don't know how to show how you can go from $A$ to row reduced form and $B$ to row reduced form using the operations. If you apply them in reverse then you can go from the row reduced form to both $A$ and $B$. And therefore you can go, using row operations, from $A$ to the row reduced form to $B$?

Comment: You’ve got the right idea. Elementary row operations are all reversible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\tilde R_1\cdots\tilde  R_kA = D$ and $R_1\cdots R_m B = D$ where the $R_i$ and $\tilde R_i$ are the matrices associated to row operations, then, as row operations are invertible, it holds
$$B = R_m^{-1}\cdots R_1^{-1}D=R_m^{-1}\cdots R_1^{-1}\tilde R_1\cdots \tilde R_kA$$